# Java / Spring thread with progress status

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, task, future

In my web app I have to run an async job, I would like to manage a progress bar in the client with the job progress.
Is there something ready-to-use in the standard Java or Spring package?

I looked for Future objects but seems not good for my purpose.

Comment: Which kind of application do you have?

Answer (score 1):

In a web project I implemented something similar.

In my controller I had a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
Integer getProgressStatus() {

    // check task running

    return progress;
}
```

Then in my page I called asynchronously the method and checked if percentage was < 100.

For example using JQuery:

```
function waitForTaskFinish() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : '/status',
        cache : false,
        success : function(data) {
            if (data < 100) {
                // display percentage...

                setTimeout("waitForTaskFinish()", 5000);
            }
            else{
                // your code
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The `// check task running` part is basically what OP was asking for.